# Where is the corresponding gap in a relative clause？

Tags: relative-clauses, gapping

> But I would be interested to read what others have to say on this.

Where is the corresponding gap in the relative clause located?

> But I would be interested to read **what others have to say___ on this.**

or

> But I would be interested to read **what others have___ to say on this.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The idiom is *have X to say about Y*, so the gap falls after *have*:

> Others have X to say about this.